# OIDC and SAML with spring boot 2.5

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, openid-connect, saml

i am working on to integration SAML and OIDC along with  Database authentication spring security ( using spring boot starter 2.5.4 )

I have done database authentication  with customAuthenticationProvider and CustomAuthenticationEntrypoint ( to make compatible with legacy encryption algo).

I am managed to use OIDC alone but I am looking for pointer to use  SAML and OIDC together in spring security .
is there any project which i can refer to or is it not possible.

Update :-
i am able to achieve to use SAML , OIDC and DB authentication together in single project based on choosen auth mechanism ( OIDC+DB or SAML+DB).

```
public void configAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception 
{
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);
        auth.authenticationProvider(samlAuthenticationProvider);

    }
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable();
    if(!samlAuth) {
        LOG.info(">>>>>>>>>>> Starting OIDC authentication1");
        http
                .authorizeRequests(authorizeRequests -> authorizeRequests
                         .antMatchers("/rest/api/v1/users/**").permitAll()
                        .antMatchers("/rest/api/v1/users/current").permitAll()
                        .antMatchers("/ui/oidc/").authenticated()
                        .antMatchers("/error").permitAll()
                        .antMatchers("/ui/app/**").permitAll()
                        .antMatchers("/ui/app/").permitAll()
                )
                .oauth2Login()
                .successHandler(new AuthenticationSuccessHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                                        Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
                        // run custom logics upon successful login
                        System.out.println(authentication.getPrincipal());
                        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(customOauth2loginProvider.authenticate(authentication));
                        handle(request, response, authentication);
                    }
                });

        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/ui/app/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/rest/api/v1/**").authenticated()
                .antMatchers("/ui/app/welcome").authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(new DBAuthenticationEntryPoint());
    } else {
        LOG.info(">>>>>>>>>>>  Starting SAML authentication");

        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/v1/users/**").authenticated()
                .antMatchers("/saml/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/saml/sso").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/ui/saml/").authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic().authenticationEntryPoint((request, response, authException) -> {
                    if (request.getRequestURI().endsWith("/ui/saml/")) {
                        System.out.println(" <<<request.getRequestURI() saml >>" + request.getRequestURI());
                        samlEntryPoint.commence(request, response, authException);
                    }
                });

        http
                .addFilterBefore(metadataGeneratorFilter(), ChannelProcessingFilter.class)
                .addFilterAfter(samlFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .addFilterBefore(samlFilter(), CsrfFilter.class);

    }

    http.sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED)
            .and()
            .addFilterAfter(expiredSessionFilter(), SessionManagementFilter.class);

    http.logout()
            .logoutUrl("/rest/api/v1/users/logout")
            .invalidateHttpSession(true)
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/ui/app/")
            .logoutSuccessHandler(new HttpStatusReturningLogoutSuccessHandler(HttpStatus.OK))
            .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID");

    http.sessionManagement()
            .sessionFixation().migrateSession();
}
```

Above code is doing logout and session expiration correctly but redirect to login page if session expire and page refresh is not working .

Comment: Can you describe what behaviour you would like to achieve? Will different endpoints have different authentication/authorization mechanisms?

Comment: same endpoint  should be able to authenticated by any one of the mechanism - user should be able to configure OIDC or SAML mechanism and if nothing was configured in application properties file than by default database authentication will be available  to both kind of mechanism. but from spring security point of view all three are required